# C++ Abort() has been called when I input extremely long string to get substring

Tags: c++, abort

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sam-and-substrings/problem

This is the problem I'm working on it and I have a problem.

Here is my code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
double const modulo = 1000000007;

int main()
{
    std::string n("");
    std::cin >> n;
    long sum(0);
    std::vector<std::string> newlyAddedSubstring;

    for (auto i : n)
    {
        for (auto &j : newlyAddedSubstring)
        {
            j += i;
            long d = std::fmod(std::stod(j), modulo);
            sum = std::fmod(sum + d, modulo);
        }
        newlyAddedSubstring.push_back(std::string(1, i)); 
        newlyAddedSubstring.back();
        sum = std::fmod(sum + (i - '0'), modulo);
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

This is a part of input and input is actually 1003 size long
630078954945407486971302572117011329116721271139829179349572383637541443562605787816061110360853600744212572072073871985233228681677019488795915592613136558538697419369158961413804139004860949683711756764106408843746324318507090...

It has no problem until around 327 repetition(i.e size of newlyAddedSubstring is around 327)  but it got problem on

```
long d = std::fmod(std::stod(j), modulo);
```

Any comments or feedback would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please compile and run the program yourself and you will get a much better error message than "abort() has been called".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::stod` throws the exception `std::out_of_range` if the value that it parsed from the string it outside the range of values that `double` can hold.

The largest value that a typical `double` implementation can hold is roughly 300 digits long. Your number is larger than that.

The exception is therefore thrown and because you don't catch it `std::terminate` is called, which by default calls `std::abort`, terminating the program.

You cannot store such a large number in a `double`. You can try `std::stold` instead, which tries to parse the number as `long double`, which *may* be larger than `double` and *may* be able to hold your value.

Also, in general, floating-point values are not able to represent integers *exactly*. Therefore it is pretty pointless to do the modulo operation on the `double` or `long double` as you are doing. It will not give an exact result and for very large values will essentially generate random values.

If you want to do exact modulo on such a large integer, you need an arbitrary-size integer library or you need to implement the modulo operation yourself.